# terraform google_bigquery_job and table schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create a big query table (with one field having MODE as REQUIRED and DESC as "SomeDesc") using terraform and then want to insert record into that table. After this resource is created, I am trying to insert a record in the same table using google_bigquery_job resource which inserts a record but converts MODE to NULLABLE and DESC to "".  How can I insert record without affecting table schema using google_bigquery_job otherwise next time it will flag it as update to existing table during terraform deployment.

**Schema file has following attribues:**

```
[
    {
      "name": "myfield",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "description": "SomeDesc"
    }
]
```

**Table Resource:**

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "xyz" {
  dataset_id          = google_bigquery_dataset.xyz.dataset_id
  table_id            = "xyz"
  description         = "Contains some value"
  project             = var.project_id
  labels              = merge(local.default_labels, { "workload2" : "test" })
  deletion_protection = var.deletion_protection

  schema = file("${path.module}/bigquery-schema/xyz.json")
}
```

**google_biguqery_job resource**

```
resource "google_bigquery_job" "xyz" {
  job_id = "xyz_insert_${uuid()}"
  labels = merge(local.default_labels, { "workload2" : "test" })
  project = var.project_id
  location = var.location
 
  query {
    query = "select 'test' as myfield"
 
    destination_table {
      project_id = google_bigquery_table.xyz.project
      dataset_id = google_bigquery_table.xyz.dataset_id 
      table_id = google_bigquery_table.xyz.table_id
    } 
 
    create_disposition = "CREATE_NEVER"
    write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
 
    allow_large_results = true
    flatten_results = true
    script_options {
      key_result_statement = "LAST"
    }
  }
}
```